# converting datetime from local to UTC and vise versa

Tags: vb.net, datetime, utc, datetime-format

I thought I figured out how to do this but it seems that I'm doing it all wrong. I have two dates, one being a published datetime which is retrieved from a json feed and is set in UTC. 
I then use the MSQM.message.arrivedtime which I am told is set to your computer time (local) for the other date as the fetch date but I convert it into UTC. Now the problem is that sometimes the fetch date is before the published datetime which should not be the case. Here is a part of my work flow:

```
 fetchDate as string = message.ArrivedTime.ToString
     ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

....example date :  2012-12-05 07:59:12
then some more code and other functions...This is the parsed out published datetime

2012-12-05 12:59:34

So now I convert the fetchDate to UTC:

```
Dim nowDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact
    (fetchDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
fetchDate = nowDate.ToUniversalTime.ToString
 ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now fetchDate = 2012-12-05 12:59:12

This is one case. Why is this so, can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How does UTC time `2012-12-05 07:59:12` turn into `2012-12-05 12:59:34` ? I am unaware of any timezone adjustment that includes 22 seconds between itself and UTC. Where is this TZ? Or did I misunderstand the example given?

Comment: no the conversion was between 2012-12-05 07:59:12 to  2012-12-05 12:59:12...that is 5 hours...anyway I made one correction and it seems fine now..still testing though...changed the format from yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss   to yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss

Comment: nope that doesnt work i guess

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the client's (or servers) clock is not correct?